# Why is pork pink after roasting to 205 F?

Tags: pork

I have browned then roasted a 6 lb. pork shoulder in a covered pan in an oven set to 275 F for 5+ hours. The results were excellent , very tender and moist and high gelatin/protein stock. I started with one cup+ of liquid ( wine, lemon juice, honey, soy sauce, liquid smoke, Worcester , etc). It reached 205 F internal temperature , measured with an accurate electronic thermometer . When cool and sliced it was pink below the surface.  Is pink color normal for well done pork ?

Comment: Different question ,I did not ask if it was done., I know the thermometer is accurate as stated in the question . My question is ; why is cooked pork pink?

Answer (score 0):

Color is not necessarily an accurate indicator of doneness.  The only way to check this is to be sure that your thermometer is accurate, and that you placed the probe at the center of your roast.  You can check the accuracy by using ice water (or boiling water...ice water is safer).